# Compilation of m4 1.4.10 to 1.4.18 fails due to "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform!" on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: compiling, glibc, gnu

The building of tarball releases of GNU m4 1.4.10 to 1.4.18 (didn't test all hotfix versions, but I assume the error is consistent among this range) with `./configure && make -j1` and git `git` repository http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/m4.git with `./bootstrap && ./configure && make -j1` (commit `cvs-readonly-359-gd69fa528` i.e. `HEAD` of `master`) fails due to

```
freadahead.c: In function 'freadahead':
freadahead.c:92:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
   ^~~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1910: freadahead.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/data/sources/m4-1.4.18/lib'
```

I'm very confused by this error and according to a superficial google search the problem is the consequence of an overly long ignored upstream update, see e.g. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1573342 with the genius documentation of the fix "Thanks for the bug report, fixed!" - if that doesn't help others...

I tried to build glibc from source and install it into a custom prefix[1]. 2.28 and 2.27 exhibit the same issue and 2.26 fails due to

```
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26/inet“ wird betreten
gcc ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/if_index.c -c -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -fno-stack-protector -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition     -ftls-model=initial-exec   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE   -I../include -I/mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/inet  -I/mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/x86/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu/include -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/float128  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96/include -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC     -DTOP_NAMESPACE=glibc -o /mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/inet/if_index.o -MD -MP -MF /mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/inet/if_index.o.dt -MT /mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/inet/if_index.o
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/if_index.c: In function ‘__if_nametoindex’:
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/if_index.c:46:3: error: ‘strncpy’ specified bound 16 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
   strncpy (ifr.ifr_name, ifname, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/sysd-rules:213: /mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26-build/inet/if_index.o] Fehler 1
make[2]: Verzeichnis „/mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26/inet“ wird verlassen
make[1]: *** [Makefile:215: inet/subdir_lib] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.26“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Fehler 2
```

and 2.25 due to

```
strftime_l.c: In function ‘__strftime_internal’:
strftime_l.c:719:4: error: macro expands to multiple statements [-Werror=multistatement-macros]
    digits = d > width ? d : width;          \
    ^~~~~~
strftime_l.c:1260:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘DO_NUMBER’
      DO_NUMBER (1, tp->tm_year + TM_YEAR_BASE);
      ^~~~~~~~~
strftime_l.c:1259:4: note: some parts of macro expansion are not guarded by this ‘else’ clause
    else
    ^~~~
In file included from wcsftime_l.c:23:
strftime_l.c: In function ‘__strftime_internal’:
strftime_l.c:719:4: error: macro expands to multiple statements [-Werror=multistatement-macros]
    digits = d > width ? d : width;          \
    ^~~~~~
strftime_l.c:1260:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘DO_NUMBER’
      DO_NUMBER (1, tp->tm_year + TM_YEAR_BASE);
      ^~~~~~~~~
strftime_l.c:1259:4: note: some parts of macro expansion are not guarded by this ‘else’ clause
    else
    ^~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [../o-iterator.mk:9: /mnt/data/sources/glibc-2.25-build/time/strftime_l.os] Fehler 1
```

which made me decide to not try out further version.

[The discussion on a report about a similar issue in findutils] suggests to overwrite `freadahead.{c,h}` from an up-to-date gnulib source root. This causes a chain of problems which is unnecessary to document here as I don't know what I'm doing.

How to get started with fixing, reporting and/or working around this issue?

I'm building m4 from source for a bootstrap script for systems where a user doesn't have privileges to use the package manager. I'm really just interested in building the original GNU m4 from release source tarballs.

An overview of build results on other similarily bare systems is provided at https://gitlab.com/krichter/m4/pipelines/36977411.

---

[1] In case you're investigating this always install glibc into a custom prefix because an installation in the default prefix `/usr/local` will most certainly ruine your system. Consider using `checkinstall` to be sure.

Comment: What was wrong with `m4` package from the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=m4)? Why do you think that `sudo apt install m4` does not suite your needs? Also if you want to successfully compile it from sources - start with `sudo apt-get build-dep m4`...

Comment: @N0rbert good point, question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to build m4 from source then start by getting its build dependencies from the repository:

1. enable *Source code* in the *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. install needed build tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
3. get necessary build dependencies for current `m4` binary package

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep m4
   ```
4. get source code of the current `m4` binary package (with all needed patches provided by Debian and/or Ubuntu):

   ```
   apt-get source m4
   cd m4-*
   ```
5. then compile it as usual

Comment: This is a good idea, however it introduces a specific handling of Ubuntu in my bootstrap script which is a larger technical dept. Think of the question as one about running third-party application (GNU m4 vs. the version patched by Ubuntu).

Answer (score 6):

Try applying [this patch](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506235359/http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4/m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch). It is an OpenEmbedded-generated backport of upstream patch.

Comment: I am trying to build an old toolchain and this was the right solution for me, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me with with `m4-1.4.18` and `glibc-2.32`. Thanks!

Comment: How do I install this patch? Sorry about the naive question. I'm on WSL2 and I can't compile a software due to the same issue as OP.